# reset password error in express.js/node.js

Tags: node.js, express

When I send a POST request the password actually changes but `resetToken` is not changing according to the code.

```js
exports.postSaveNewPassword = (req,res,next)=>{
    const errors = validationResult(req)
    if(!errors.isEmpty()){
        return next(errors.array())
    }
    User.findOne({_id:req.body.id})
    .then(user=>{
        return bcrypt.hash(req.body.password,12)
        .then(pass=>{
            user.password = pass;
            user.resetTokenExpiration = undefined;
            user.resetToken = undefined; // this line is giving error
            return user.save()
        })
        .then(()=>{
            res.redirect("/")
        })
    })
    .catch(err=>{
        next(err)
    })
}
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'resetToken' of null
    at E:\backhand\authentication\controllers\auth.js:117:29
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Note: I'm assuming that you mixed up something here and the code where this exact error message belongs to had the line `user.resetToken = undefined;` first, not `user.password = pass;`. Anything else wouldn't make sense because `user` cannot be first an object and then suddenly null.*

The issue: `user` is null. Therefore, you are essentially doing `null.resetToken = undefined` which is not possible because, as the error said, the computer "cannot set property 'resetToken' of null".

This is probably the case because no user with the given ID was found. (You should always check for that, even if you think it should normally not happen, because you can't prevent invalid IDs from being sent to your server.)

You should check what value `req.body.id` has. Your frontend is not sending this parameter correctly (or it is not sending the content type correctly, so `req.body` may be a string or buffer instead of an object).